# Auto Select Text of Input Field when Dropdown Opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into an issue where I want to have the input field text automatically highlighted when I open a dropdown. From a user point of view I want them to be able to copy this link to their clipboard pressing CTRL C so i want it automatically selected for that reason.

My Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/Yppqw/11/

My Input belongs to a Bootstrap Dropdown and is set up to pull the current URL.

and the JavaScript I am using to try and do this is as follows

```
$(function () {
  /* Add Current URL to Input Field */
  $('input.shareURL').val(window.location);

  /*  Select input field text automatically*/ 
  $('input.shareURL').select();
});


/*  Stop Dropdown from closing when input clicked */
$('.inputDrop').find('input').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

How Can I get this input field to already be selected when I open the dropdown?

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yppqw/18/. Doesn't use any timeouts.

Comment: @PetrČihula, nice, but this solution is not working with the Bootstrap JS file loaded into resources http://jsfiddle.net/Yppqw/19/ I see you removed it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually when you open the `textbox` it is `invisible` to `DOM`, so it does not `select text`,
So wait for `200 ms` and then `select text` like,

```
  $('button').on('click',function(){
       setTimeout(function(){$('input.shareURL').select();},200);
  });
```

Test [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yppqw/17/)

Comment: I tried that and did not work. Do you have a working jsfiddle with that solution?

Comment: @Redwall Test the above answer I have made changes in it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know why it needed a timeout to work? Would be interested to know...I edited the "200" -> "1" to make it faster at highlighting. Thanks for solving...EDIT: Sorry read your explanation why :)

Comment: Yes when you click on button then the `div` having `class` `btn-group dropdown` add one more class `open` and you are using `bootstrap` so if you see `bootstrap.css line 3008` you will find `.open > .dropdown-menu{ display:block;}` so your `input box in ul` will be `visible` to `DOM`. Above process takes some `milliseconds` to show the `input element`, so I used `200 ms` for that.